# The number of lines intersecting $n$ given lines (not all coplanar) in a three dimensional space

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

Given $n$ lines $(n\ge 3)$ in a three-dimensional space (not all coplanar). How many lines will intersect these $n$ lines in our space?

Comment: Seems likely there are a lot of cases, besides the one case "not all coplanar".

Answer (score 2):

This is classical algebraic geometry. For $n=3$ there are infinitely many
lines meeting three skew lines, and they form a ruling of a quadric surface $Q$. Bringing in a fourth line in general position, this meets $Q$ in $\le2$ points (over $\Bbb R$) or in two points (over $\Bbb C$) so there will be at most $2$ lines for $n=4$. The fifth line in general position
won't meet either of these lines, so for $n\ge5$ lines in general position,
then no line meets all of them.